# c# - Simple phonebook homework

Tags: c#

One of the programs I have to write for homework is to make a phonebook.

> Write a program that receives some info from the console about people and their phone numbers.
>   You are free to choose the manner in which the data is entered; each entry should have just one name and one number (both of them strings). If you receive a name that already exists in the phonebook, simply update its number.
>   After filling this simple phonebook, upon receiving the command "search", and the command “stop”, your program should be able to perform a search of a contact by name and print her details in format "{name} -> {number}". In case the contact isn't found, print "Contact {name} does not exist."

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class Phonebook
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] input = new string[100];
        input[1] = string.Empty;
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (input[0] != "search")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine().Split('-');
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(input[i]))
                {
                    dict.Remove(input[i]);
                }
            dict.Add(input[0],input[1]);
            }
        }
        while (input[0] != "stop")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> c in dict)
            {
                if (input[i] == c.Key)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", c.Key, c.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Contact {0} does not exist.", c.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this at line 27 after I enter a pair in the console:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has alr
>   eady been added.

Comment: Whatever line 27 is, at runtime you're trying to add an element to a dictionary which already contains an element for the given key.  As the error tells you, you can't do that.  This is a good opportunity to step through the code in a debugger and determine what's actually going on and why you think it should be different.

Comment: Simple google search returns multiple duplicates.

Comment: What about that very descriptive error message are you not understanding?

Comment: How can something exist if I haven't added it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue

```
while (input[0] != "search")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine().Split('-');
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(input[i]))
                {
                    dict.Remove(input[i]);
                }
            dict.Add(input[0],input[1]);
            }
        }
```

You remove `input[i]` key and try to add `input[0]` key.